# Duda con Expresiones regulares (Java)

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, algoritmos

Hola gente como estan? A ver si me echan una mano, estoy practicando expresiones regulares y es todo absolutamente nuevo, he creado el siguiente ejemplo en el que quiero encontrar la v mayuscula (blancoVerdeazul) para poder hacer uso de split y dividirlo en dos (blanco Verdeazul) pero hay algo que estoy haciendo mal

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
          String str = "blancoVerdeazul";
          String [] cadenas = str.split("[\\V]");
        
         for(int i=0; i<= cadenas.length; i++) {
             
             System.out.println(cadenas[i]);
         }
             
             

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
String [] cadenas = str.split("(?=V)");
```

Cuida la condición del `for` porque te lanzará un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` debido a la condición `<=`. Cámbiala por `<`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "blancoVerdeazul";
    String [] cadenas = str.split("(?=V)");

    for(int i = 0; i < cadenas.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(cadenas[i]);
    }
}
```